# Wait for mouseclick in function

Tags: c#

In one of my classes I got `List<Point> mousePointList = clickArea.getClicks();`

The function getClicks() should return a list of points that contains an entry for every click made after executing the function. After clicking multiple times you should be able to finish the function with an ENTER click.

My problem is that I can't get the function to wait for the MouseClick function.

Comment: This is a pretty simple task. Make the List a global variable. Set the list to a new list on button click. Make a boolean that when button is clicked you turn to true. On mouse click event check if bool is true. if it is true add to the list. On enter button grab all mouse clicks from list.

Comment: This function should use IoC (inversion of control) logic, with less sophisticated words this case: event driven logic. The solution will be more an event collecting class than a simple function. However the concate implementation depends on you UI framework: What UI do you use: WPF or the legacy WinForms. Or is this some non Microsoft UI like Xamarin or Unity what you program in C#?

Comment: I use legacy WinForms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got your logic wrong. You can't wait for a mouse click, instead you will just receive an event (through your `Form`s [`MouseClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick(v=vs.110).aspx) event or so) and you will act accordingly.

You can do the same for the `ENTER`: if someone hits `ENTER` and you don't allow it yet, don't handle the event any further. You can use the [`KeyDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx) event for that.

Comment: Thank you. I'm allways pleased if someone answers also questions of newbies.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to wait for `MouseClick`. What you want to do is wire up a continuation from inside of your function:

```
void Main()
{
    Form frm = new Form();
    var btn = new Button { Text = "Start" };
    btn.Click += (_, __) =>
        {
            var clicks = new List<Point>();

            MouseEventHandler mouseUp = (s, e) =>
                {
                    clicks.Add(e.Location);
                };

            var eventHelper = new EventHelper { MouseUp = mouseUp };

            KeyEventHandler keyUp = (s, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
                    {
                        frm.MouseUp -= eventHelper.MouseUp;
                        frm.KeyUp -= eventHelper.KeyUp;
                        btn.Enabled = true;

                        // Finish
                        clicks.Dump();
                    }
                };

            eventHelper.KeyUp = keyUp;

            frm.MouseUp += mouseUp;
            frm.KeyUp += keyUp;
            btn.Enabled = false;
        };

    frm.Controls.Add(btn);

    Application.Run(frm);
}

class EventHelper
{
    public MouseEventHandler MouseUp;
    public KeyEventHandler KeyUp;
}
```

Note that the `clicks` variable stays local - there's no need to explicitly define a field on the whole form or anything like that. Registering and unregistering the event handlers is a bit clunky, but I hope this shows the intent clearly enough. Do not forget that the event handlers are global, though - if there's more buttons that can be possibly waiting for those events as well, they'll *all* be receiving at the same time. This may or may not be a problem, depending on your exact scenario (but it's inherent to simply having a single form - there isn't really a way around this other than disabling all the conflicting buttons when one of them is pressed).

It's also quite easy to utilize `await` to avoid having to write the callback manually - I'll leave that as an excercise for the reader :) This is very handy for reliability - the sample code can easily lead to the button being disabled forever, as well as leaving the event handlers assigned forever if there's an exception somewhere. With `await`, you'd just use try-finally to handle removing the event handlers and enabling the button again.